# R glm prediction and target variable inversed

Tags: r, prediction

I'd like to predict a target variable(IS_MALE) with a glm:

If a user is a male, the IS_MALE=1, else the IS_MALE=0

When I use prediction to predict the gender of new record, the more I raise the threshold of prediction in order to be sure that the user is a male, the more I have error in male prediction. Actually, I was waiting for the opposite

Here is the code :

```
  prediction <- ifelse(predict(model, data, type='response') >0.5, 1, 0)
```

Does R inverse the value of the target variable ?

Comment: Raising the threshold above the observed proportion of Males in the sample _would_ be expected to increase the errors. You are creating more "false negatives".

Comment: I think I found my mystake. I divided by the number of male instead of the number of predicted male to have the error rate. Both seems useful, but here I need this error rate